# Auto Save when editing Careers profile

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

I was typing in my experience details in the StackOverflow careers profile page. I accidentally swiped left on my Macbook trackpad which caused the browser to go back and I lost my details.

Could you please add auto-save functionality. Having a save button seems to be an anti-pattern these days.

This is important information and recruiters would not like to see incomplete details. Maybe you could store the details in localStorage and show the unsaved details to the developer when he/she navigates back to the page.

Comment: Oh, the legendary usability of OS X. I enjoy it too.

Comment: Although I do prefer the title of this one, bearing as it does some relation to what the OP actually means.